# User Accounts for Hadoop Daemons

Tags: hadoop

I read the Hadoop in Secure Mode Documentation. Right now all my daemons are running under one single account. The Doc suggests to run different daemons under different account. What is the purpose for doing that?

[Link to Hadoop in Secure Mode Doc](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SecureMode.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally good practice to use separate dedicated service accounts for different server processes where possible.  This limits attack surface in the event that an attacker compromises one of the processes.  For example, if an attacker compromised process A, then the attacker could do things like access files owned by the account running process A.  If process B used the same account as process A, then files created by process B would also be compromised.  By using a separate account for process B, we can limit the impact of a vulnerability.

Aside from that general principle, there are other considerations specific to the implementation of Hadoop that make it desirable to use separate accounts.

HDFS has a concept of the [super-user](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsPermissionsGuide.html#The_Super-User).  The HDFS super-user is the account that is running the NameNode process.  The super-user has special privileges to run HDFS administration commands and access all files in HDFS, regardless of the permission settings on those files.  YARN and MapReduce daemons do not require HDFS super-user privilege.  They can operate as an unprivileged user of HDFS, accessing only files for which they have permission.  Running everything with the same account would unintentionally escalate privileges for the YARN and MapReduce daemons.

When running in secured mode, the YARN NodeManager utilizes the [LinuxContainerExecutor](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SecureMode.html#LinuxContainerExecutor) to launch container processes as the user who submitted the YARN application.  This works by using a special [setuid](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setuid) executable, which allows the user running the NodeManager to switch to running a process as the user who submitted the application.  This ensures that users submitting applications cannot escalate privileges by running code in the context of a different user account.  However, setuid executables themselves are powerful tools that can cause privilege escalation problems if used incorrectly.  The LinuxContainerExecutor documentation describes very specific steps to take in setting the permissions and configuration for this setuid executable.  If a separate account was not used for running the YARN daemons, then this setuid executable would have to be made accessible to a larger set of accounts, which would increase the attack surface.